# how to efficiently enable/disable GUI in ubuntu server 12.04?

Tags: server, gui, xserver

I am using Ubuntu Server 12.04 and I intend to use some graphical tools to administrate the server. That's why I installed `ubuntu-desktop`:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

And I enabled it with:

```
startx
```

However, as soon as I finish with the administration I would like to disable it without leaving background processes consuming the CPU.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply remove lightdm and use startx to manually start your X sessions.

`sudo apt-get remove lightdm`

This will remove the ubuntu-desktop meta package.

You can also edit /etc/default/grub

and change

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”

to

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”text”

then run

> sudo update-grub

Comment: just to make it clear, choose one option or the other. There is no need to choose both options. I prefer to remove lightdm (or other managers) but changing the grub config seems to be the more "supported" method.

Comment: What about the GRUB_TERMINAL command?

Comment: What command do you write to disable the GUI?